# How to select every tag from XML document in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I'm looking if it is possible to make query in T-SQL that will select value from **every** tag of my XML document.

I don't know how many tags there can be, and i don't know their names, because it should be dynamic...
It is not important format of output (it can be  manipulated later), only thing that is matter is that I get data from every tag :)

*Thanks*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '..... add your XML here........'

SELECT 
    NodeName = Nod.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    NodeValue = Nod.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @input.nodes('//*') AS TBL(Nod)
```

This will list all nodes - name and value - in your XML.

WARNING: I just picked `varchar(50)` at random here, as the datatype for the XML node element. If that's not suitable for you - adapt as needed! Since you're converting them all at once, you have to convert them all to the same datatype - and `varchar` seems like a fairly safe choice :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @xml xml

select 
    x.n.query('local-name(.)'),
    x.n.value('(text())[1]','varchar(100)')
from @xml.nodes('//.') x(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`openxml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx) to get an **edge** table. It will give you node values as well as attribute values. If you have complex XML with a mix of nodes and text you will get the values split in separate rows.

```sql
declare @xml xml

set @xml = 
'<root Attrib="RootAttribute">
  <item>Value item 1</item>
  <item>
    Value item 2
      <subitem>sub value in 2</subitem>
    More text in item 2
  </item>
 </root>'

declare @idoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @xml

select *
from openxml(@idoc, '')

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Result:

```
id parentid nodetype localname prefix namespaceuri datatype prev text
0  NULL     1        root      NULL   NULL         NULL     NULL NULL
2  0        2        Attrib    NULL   NULL         NULL     NULL NULL
8  2        3        #text     NULL   NULL         NULL     NULL RootAttribute
3  0        1        item      NULL   NULL         NULL     NULL NULL
9  3        3        #text     NULL   NULL         NULL     NULL Value item 1
4  0        1        item      NULL   NULL         NULL     3    NULL
6  4        3        #text     NULL   NULL         NULL     NULL Value item 2
5  4        1        subitem   NULL   NULL         NULL     6    NULL
10 5        3        #text     NULL   NULL         NULL     NULL sub value in 2
7  4        3        #text     NULL   NULL         NULL     5    More text in item 2
```